# Fit image over a set of points (shape)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision

I have a face image that has labelled face features (matrix stored in `[x y]` format)

[image: labelled frontal face]

I have generated depth information (a 3d mesh) for each of the labelled points, and have a matrix in `[x y z]` format, where the coordinates x and y are the same as that of the points.

The mesh looks like this:
[image: 3d_mesh]

How do I fit or warp the original image (at least the region enclosed by the points) over the 3d mesh, using the x and y coordinates for mapping? *I know I have to do a lot of interpolation in the 3d mesh before I see good results, but I'd like to know how to fit an image to that*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign specific RGB colours to 3d mesh/surface/points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899417/assign-specific-rgb-colours-to-3d-mesh-surface-points)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the standard 3D technics:

1. Build mesh based on your point cloud. You need something that can be properly warped. For facial animation in CGI they use topology like this one so it can be properly animated(warped): [image]
   I will use regular mesh just to show core concept: 
   [image]
2. Map your image to this mesh using  [Texture Mapping](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html)
   [image]
3. Apply warping(in my case it's just bending):
   [image] 
   [image]

   [Puppet Warp tool in Photoshop CS5 works in similar way.](http://polygonspixelsandpaint.tumblr.com/post/5335098335)

Comment: any idea how to do this in Matlab?

Comment: @tdk You need simple 3D engine. Other than that it's a trivial task and requires minimal amount of code. Except building proper topology might be tricky. + you will have access to high quality texture filtering.