# Assign specific RGB colours to 3d mesh/surface/points

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision

#### Face and feature landmarks

I have a face image that has labelled face features. The image is stored in standard JPEG format and the landmarks are stored in `[x y]` format (x,y of point corresponds to its coordinates on the image as shown below)

[image: labelled frontal face]

---

#### Interpolated 3d face mesh

I have generated depth information (a 3d mesh) for each of the labelled points, and have a matrix in `[x y z]` format, where the coordinates x and y are the same as that of the points.

The sparse mesh looks like this:
[image: 3d_mesh]

I then interpolated over `xrange`, `yrange` and `zrange` to get a better mesh. Using `mesh(xrange,yrange,zrange)` gives me the following
[image: interpolated 3d mesh]

The colours for face image pixels can be obtained using `imread(face_image.jpg)`.
Given that the (x,y) value of each of the interpolated point corresponds to (x,y) in the image, is it possible to make the colour of the pixel at **(x,y,z)[3dmesh]** the same as colour of **(x,y)[face image]**?

This would effectively superimpose/warp the face on the3d mesh, giving me a 3d face model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
n=50000; % chose something appropriate
[C,map] = rgb2ind(FaceImageRGB,n);
```

To map the color in your RGB image into a linear index. **Make sure the mesh and the RGB image have the same x-y dimensions**.

Then use `surf` to plot the surface with the indexed values for color (should be in the form `surf(X,Y,Z,C)`) and the `map` as color map.

```
surf(3dmesh, C), shading flat;
colormap(map);
```

**Edit:** a working example (with a *colorful* image this time...):

```
rgbim=imread('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Loriculus_vernalis_-Ganeshgudi,_Karnataka,_India_-male-8-1c.jpg');

n=50000; % chose something apropriate
[C,map] = rgb2ind(rgbim,n);    

% Creation of mesh with the same dimensions as the image:
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-floor(size(rgbim, 2)/2):floor(size(rgbim, 2)/2), -floor(size(rgbim, 1)/2):floor(size(rgbim, 1)/2));

% An arbitrary function for Z:
Z=-(X.^2+Y.^2);

% Display the surface with the image as color value:
surf(X, Y, Z, double(C)), shading flat
colormap(map);
```

Result:

[image: mapped parrot]

Comment: your example works perfectly. unfortunately, using the meshgrid similar to what you've used doesn't interpolate (added more details to the question) my face fully (I'm a newbie and don't understand the negative indices used, so I assume it must a range issue). Also, `surf(X, Y, -Z, double(C))`, shading flat gives me **Warning: size(CData) must equal size(ZData) or size(ZData)-1 for flat shading**

Comment: @tdk In my example I chose an arbitrary function to create `Z`, I used `-Z` to flip the polynomial. It is irrelevant to your application. Use `Z`instead (will edit in my answer). For the rest, make sure the size of the mesh matches the size of the image, either pad the mesh or resize the image (using `imresize`maybe).

Comment: I was confused with `-floor(size(rgbim, 2)/2` being used as a lower bound. The error was due to a dimension mismatch in

Comment: @tdk This was only for demonstration purposes, I wanted the mesh to be the size of the image and go from -1/2 the size to +1/2 the size. You don't need that part, just match the dimensions of both.

Comment: I've fixed that now, but I've got other problems. The face (different from the one above) appears too dirty (http://i.imgur.com/q1mBYiv.jpg). I tried using `n=1000`, but same result(http://i.imgur.com/DOsySv9.jpg). Interpolating the picture(i.e. the RGB mesh) and using a better mesh makes it worse(http://imgur.com/ikaBQel)